# Python - Why after removing the widget, and then adding it from another method fails to add the same widgets?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

Why the redrawing of the buttons fail? First it launch where i have the buttons, then i want to resize the window on top in lower height and then reduce the buttons also in another size, but the redrawing of buttons from method buttononTop() is failing.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk, gtk, gobject

class GTK_Main:

  def __init__(self):

    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_default_size(800, 768)
    self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")
    self.vbox = gtk.VBox()
    self.window.add(self.vbox)
    self.hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False)    
    self.hbox.set_border_width(10)
    self.hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(), True, True, 0)
    self.button2 = gtk.Button("Quit")
    self.button2.connect("clicked", self.exit)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button2, False)
    self.button3 = gtk.Button("Test")
    self.button3.connect("clicked", self.buttononTop)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button3, False)    
    self.hbox.add(gtk.Label())
    self.window.show_all()

  def buttononTop(self, w):
    print "Buttons on top - redraw with different shapes includeing the window"
    self.window.remove(self.vbox)
    self.window.resize(800, 330)
    self.window.set_size_request(800, 330)
    # ------------------------------------------- [FAILS STARTS]
    self.vbox = gtk.VBox()
    self.window.add(self.vbox)
    self.hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False)    
    self.hbox.set_border_width(10)
    self.hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(), True, True, 0)
    self.button2 = gtk.Button("Quit")
    self.button2.connect("clicked", self.exit)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button2, False)
    self.button3 = gtk.Button("Test")
    self.button3.connect("clicked", self.buttononTop)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button3, False)    
    self.hbox.add(gtk.Label())
    # ------------------------------------------- [FAILS END]

  def exit(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

GTK_Main()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: @ptomato: `self.button3.connect("clicked", self.buttononTop)` once i press, it removes the widgets, but then it does not redraw all the rest like i have mentioned there.

Comment: You need to realize and show the contents of the new vbox you created in `self.vbox = gtk.VBox()` (where the fail starts), try adding `self.vbox.show_all()` after the line `self.hbox.add(gtk.Label())` and see if you get the desired results

Comment: @another.anon.coward: That is also not working when i have resize to 1280x720 to 1280x330 example here: https://gist.github.com/4222245

Comment: If you change the self.window.set_default_sized(lower, and lower) then the application works but if you set the self.window.set_default_size(higher , higher) then the resizing is not working.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I will venture a guess. The code which you have shared on gist seems to work for me (screen resolution 1366x786). It may be the case that when you set the default size very large the window is maximized (can be tracked with `window-state-event` signal, check for `new_window_state` of `event`. In case the window is maximized then resize request may not work as you want them, as maximizing and minimizing windows are handled by window manager. In this case there maybe 2 possible ways to work around this, 1) Call `unmaximize` explicitly if window is maximized ...

Comment: .. i.e. add `if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
        self.window.unmaximize()` before resizing. Please note that this *may not* work as it is a request to WM which it may choose not to honour. 2) Alternatively, you can hide the window before resizing then show it i.e. add `self.window.hide()` before `resize` and `self.window.show()` later. This *may* have some impact on your application. For better understanding of your problem, could you please let us know why would there be a need to set default size of window to a large value?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: i have added your solution to the answer. It works now thanks. Also commented why the set_default_size i used which was the only way to make it work while using dual monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @another.anon.coward, now it works according to his follow up.

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk, gtk, gobject

class GTK_Main:

  def __init__(self):

    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

    # if i use set_size_request, the first launch is not running
    # in correct screen (while using dual screen)
    #self.window.set_size_request(1280, 720)
    # therefore by using default size it fix it
    self.window.set_default_size(1280, 720)

    self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")

    self.vbox = gtk.VBox()
    self.window.add(self.vbox)
    self.hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False)    
    self.hbox.set_border_width(10)
    self.hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(), True, True, 0)
    self.button2 = gtk.Button("Quit")
    self.button2.connect("clicked", self.exit)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button2, False)
    self.button3 = gtk.Button("Test")
    self.button3.connect("clicked", self.buttononTop)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button3, False)    
    self.hbox.add(gtk.Label())
    self.window.show_all()
    # another.anon.coward: mentioned a great way solve it 
    if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
      print "unmaximize"
      self.window.unmaximize()

    self.window.move(0,0)

  def buttononTop(self, w):
    print "Buttons on top - redraw with different shapes includeing the window"
    self.window.remove(self.vbox)
    self.window.resize(1280, 100)
    # if i use set_size_request, the first launch is not running
    # in correct screen (while using dual screen)
    #self.window.set_size_request(1280, 720)
    # therefore by using default size it fix it
    self.window.set_default_size(1280, 100)

    # another.anon.coward: mentioned a great way solve it 
    if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
      print "unmaximize"
      self.window.unmaximize()

    self.window.move(0,0)
    self.window.show_all()

    # ------------------------------------------- [FAILS STARTS]
    self.vbox = gtk.VBox()
    self.window.add(self.vbox)
    self.hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False)    
    self.hbox.set_border_width(10)
    self.hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(), True, True, 0)
    self.button2 = gtk.Button("Quit")
    self.button2.connect("clicked", self.exit)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button2, False)
    self.button3 = gtk.Button("Test")
    self.button3.connect("clicked", self.buttononTop)    
    self.hbox.pack_start(self.button3, False)    
    self.hbox.add(gtk.Label())    
    # ------------------------------------------- [FAILS FIXED]    
    self.vbox.show_all()


  def exit(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

GTK_Main()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```